# S3 intelligent tiering with small objects (cloudformation template)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I've read that small objects (< 128kb) are not included in Intelligent Tiering for S3. See [link](https://awsmadeeasy.com/blog/aws-s3-intelligent-tiering/#:%7E:text=If%20there%20are%20multiple%20lifecycle%20policies%20AWS%20S3,the%20per-object%20monitoring%20would%20outweigh%20potential%20cost%20savings.). Can you overwrite that by transitioning small files yourself?

More concretely, imagine a small file (1kb) in a bucket governed by below policy. The two rules both apply, so what will happen?

A:

- 0-1 days: nothing
- 1-90 days: INTELLIGENT_TIERING, which will ignore them
- 90+ days: GLACIER

B:

- 0-1 days: nothing
- 90+ days: GLACIER

C:

- 0-1 days: nothing
- 1+ days: INTELLIGENT_TIERING, which will ignore them.

```
Resources:
  AthenaResultsS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: some-bucket
      ...
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:  
          - Id: MoveSmallFilesToGlacier
            Prefix: ""
            Status: Enabled
            ObjectSizeLessThan: 128 000  # Files this small don't get Intelligent Tiering
            Transitions:
              - TransitionInDays: 90
                StorageClass: GLACIER
          - Id: RemoveAllFiles
            Prefix: ""
            Status: Enabled
            # ObjectSizeMoreThan: 128 000  # If this is uncommented, we're in scenario B
            ExpirationInDays: 1000
            Transitions:
              - TransitionInDays: 1
                StorageClass: INTELLIGENT_TIERING
```

Comment: Your question is confusing; is your question regarding standard to intelligent tier, or standard to glacier?

Comment: More clear like this?

Comment: And is your problem understanding the above, or actually moving smaller than 128kb objects between storage tiers?

Comment: In the end, both :) Practically, I want to move small files to Glacier but I can add the ObjectSizeMoreThan for that. I just would like to understand what happens if both rules apply :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can (haven't tested it though personally) [the pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) has the information.
For IA:

> S3 Standard-IA and S3 One Zone-IA storage have a minimum billable object size of 128 KB. Smaller objects may be stored but will be charged for 128 KB of storage at the appropriate storage class rate.

For Glacier:

> S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval has a minimum billable object size of 128 KB. Smaller objects may be stored but will be charged for 128 KB of storage at the appropriate storage class rate.
> (...)
> For each object that is stored in S3 Glacier Flexible Retrieval or S3 Glacier Deep Archive, Amazon S3 adds 40 KB of chargeable overhead for metadata, with 8 KB charged at S3 Standard rates and 32 KB charged at S3 Glacier Flexible Retrieval or S3 Deep Archive rates.

So the general answer is: You can but it will be more expensive.